# How to keep WLAN connection alive in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, netctl

I'm using netctl-auto to connect automatically to WLAN. However, recently it has been dropping connections and not re-establishing them. Worse, it seems not to log anything useful when the connection is lost:

```
$ journalctl --unit=netctl-auto@wlp1s0.service --boot --output=cat | tail --lines=1
Interface 'wlp1s0' reestablished connection to network '<network name>'
```

A workaround is to run `sudo systemctl restart netctl-auto@wlp1s0.service`, but of course that doesn't scale.

There is an issue elsewhere though which seems to be related:

```
$ dmesg --notime | grep ath10k_pci
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
```

These services are running:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files --state enabled
UNIT FILE                          STATE  
org.cups.cupsd.path                enabled
acpid.service                      enabled
autovt@.service                    enabled
avahi-daemon.service               enabled
clamd.service                      enabled
cups-browsed.service               enabled
dbus-org.freedesktop.Avahi.service enabled
display-manager.service            enabled
docker.service                     enabled
freshclamd.service                 enabled
getty@.service                     enabled
ip6tables.service                  enabled
iptables.service                   enabled
lightdm.service                    enabled
netctl-auto@.service               enabled
netctl@wlp1s0\x2d<network name>.service enabled
ntpd.service                       enabled
org.cups.cupsd.service             enabled
smartd.service                     enabled
sshd.service                       enabled
tor.service                        enabled
avahi-daemon.socket                enabled
org.cups.cupsd.socket              enabled
remote-fs.target                   enabled

24 unit files listed.
```

After looking around for that I've only found a suggestion to [remove the current firmware binary](https://superproxy.crushus.com/bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1728715#p1728715), but that's also not much of a work-around. I've tried reinstalling the linux-firmware package, but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't use it, but are you sure you are supposed to have both the auto and interface services enabled? They may be conflicting...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's by design: [netctl-auto starts the relevant netctl service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless).

Comment: In that case I'd remove netctl and connect manually and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Luc33 and the Arch Linux forum members who [solved this by manually replacing the drivers](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1737681#p1737681):

1. Back up your files:

   ```
   sudo mv /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174{,.orig}
   ```
2. Get the latest drivers:

   ```
   wget https://codeload.github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/zip/master
   unzip master
   ```
3. Copy the relevant driver files into place:

   ```
   sudo cp -R ath10k-firmware-master/QCA6174 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
   ```
4. In each directory inside /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174 remove the file suffixes of the latest .bin and .txt files.
5. Reboot & enjoy!